# Best way to synchronize infrequently updated hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, synchronization, hashmap

I have a HashMap that we use in our application. The data is populated from database during application initial load and then it's always just read and never updated. There will be multiple threads constantly reading the data. Since the data is never updated, we currently don't use any synchronization and is using just the HashMap. The way we define this now is:

```
private volatile Map<Integer, MyData> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Now we want to update this data in map once a day by re-populating from the database. What I'm planning to do is get the data from database to a local map say `myLocalMap` say everyday at midnight. Once I have the data loaded from DB to `myLocalMap` I will just swap `myMap` to point to this.

So my concern is, at the point where I do `myMap = myLocalMap`, is there a possibility that some other thread that is reading data from `myMap` get an empty or unexpected result?
If yes, I will have to synchronize `myMap`. For synchronization I have the below options:

```
synchronized(myMap) {} OR // synchronize all map get and update operations
ConcurrentHashMap OR
Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap)
```

But I'm hesitant to use synchronization because then I'm synchronizing all the reads too. I think synchronizing the map for once a day process of refreshing will impact all reads of the map that constantly occurs all through the day. This is especially bad since I have many maps in my application that are read and updated this way. Any thought/comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At the point where I do myMap = myLocalMap, is there a possibility
>   that some other thread that is reading data from myMap get an empty or
>   unexpected result?

No there is not. Reads and writes [are atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) for reference variables which means the entire operation happens all at once and the results aren't visible to other threads until the entire operation is finished. Therefore, any thread reading from 'myMap' will get either the old myMap or the new myMap, but will never get an empty or inconsistent result. Additionally, using the `volatile` keyword on 'myMap' would mean that all threads will always be aware of fresh data: if myMap has been updated, any read operations that were initiated *after* the update operation started will use that updated value.

Supporting documentation from Oracle's Java tutorial:

> - Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most    primitive variables (all types except long and double).
> - any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before    relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable

[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html):

> If a variable is declared with the volatile keyword then it is
>   guaranteed that any thread that reads the field will see the most
>   recently written value.

Also from the same article on Vogella:

> The Java language specification guarantees that reading or writing a
>   variable is an atomic operation

Also see [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/) reference, specifically "Listing 3. Using a volatile variable for safe one-time publication" which describes a scenario very similar to yours.

I agree with Giovanni about ConcurrentHashMap by the way. But in your case you don't need to use ConcurrentHashMap since all of your updates occur in a single transaction and you are just adjusting the Map to point to the new data.

Comment: That was exactly what I was interested in. But I got suspicious when you deleted your comment first. As long as the read get values from old Map or the new one, I'm fine. So in that case, is it safe to assume that I can just use a plain HashMap without any synchronization or changing to ConcurrentHashMap? Thanks!

Comment: @kriver To be honest I became skeptical of my own answer. I would wait for confirmation or denial from someone more experienced or until I can find you some good reference materials. Again, Giovanni is right that the "easy" way to go is to just use ConcurrentHashMap, but it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @kriver According to this reference https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/ you have to make your 'myMap' volatile for it to be thread safe. IF myMap is volatile, then yes, my post above is correct (according to IBM's reference).

Comment: Thanks for the details and reference. I think the reference you pointed makes a good case for not synchronizing and just keeping it volatile in my scenario. But I will wait to see if someone more experienced has anything to say. :)

Comment: @kriver I'm sure this answer is correct: it was more about getting good supporting documentation and I didn't want you to just "take my word for it". If you're still uncertain I would suggest adding a bounty on the question, since it's old at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ConcurrentHashMap`. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> [...] retrieval operations do not entail locking [...]

**EDIT**: As per the comment, since your map is effectively immutable, you might as well use [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
private volatile Map<K,V> map = ImmutableMap.of();
```

The above creates an empty immutable map which is **read-only** and **thread safe** (clients can't accidentally modify it with the risk of `ConcurrentModificationException`s).

When you need to repopulate the map from the database you just build a new one:

```
ImmutableMap.Builder<K,V> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
// add your k,v pairs to the builder
builder.put(foo,bar);
// now swap the map with the new one:
map = builder.build();
```

As @KyleM noted, having the map declared volatile means that the above assignment will be [atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), i.e., once completed, all clients will see the new map. So this should solve all your concurrency concerns in two simple steps.

Note that this pattern is somewhat similar to having an immutable collection stored in a `var` in Scala.

As a side note, you should check out [Guava's caches](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained): they might solve even more problems for you.

Comment: But my first question is do I even need to synchronize myMap? I'm updating myMap just by swapping it to point to myLocalMap (no putAll or clear ops). @KyleM commented saying a read op that occurs during that time will always return either data from old map or new map, but cannot be empty. But then he deleted the comment making me suspicious of the answer.. :) So is it safe to assume that I can just use a plain HashMap without any synchronization or changing to ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: I see. Adding more to my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Giovanni, unless you want to lock out reads while you're updating your hash?  Then you might have to do some custom synchronization.

I would guess you wouldn't want a read to happen mid-update, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just swapping the attribute myMap with an already initialized map and the volatile keyword, you do not need any kind of synchronization

The ConcurrentHashMap approach would be good if you need to update some values regularly.