# What is the good way to update a map when a client may get the value from (java project)?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

In the java web project, I have a set of java bean to cache, so, I use java.lang.`HashMap` to store those objects, everytime, client get those object from this map when make a http request. But sometime, this map needs to update a few objects, in the multi-threading environment, I worry about that when one thread updating the object of map, another thread make a get operation to this map, just like this:

Thread-1:

```
map.put("user:1001", userObject);
```

Thread-2:

```
User userObject = map.get("user:1001");
```

I don't want to use synchronized strategy, so what is the good way to **update** a `map` when a client may get the value from?

Comment: Why don't you want to synchronize things?

Comment: [This SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291836/concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronized-hashmap) might be of use to you.  It sounds like you want reads and writes to the `HashMap` to happen atomically and in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Consider `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: Because there is a large amount of clients request data from this map, so, make synchronized get will increase the time of get operation, that's what i don't want.

Comment: Use a ConcurrentHashMap as suggested by coolguy. The read operations won't be locked with this. So this won't effect much on get. Only write operations are locked.

Comment: Thanks for everybody, I found this explain what i worry about:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562165/best-way-to-synchronize-infrequently-updated-hashmap